Flutter build apk android
I'm encountering an error while running the 'flutter build' command within the Flutter development environment
pubspec file:
name: app
description: app

version: 3.0.0+16

environment:
  sdk: ">=2.11.0 <3.0.0"

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  shared_preferences: ^2.0.0
  cupertino_icons: ^0.1.2
  custom_switch: ^0.0.1
  settings_ui: ^0.4.0
  animated_text_kit: ^4.2.2
  flutter_svg: ^1.0.0
  simple_permissions: any
  location: ^2.5.0
  path_provider: ^2.0.0
  percent_indicator: ^2.1.3
  rflutter_alert: ^1.0.3
  barcode_scan2: any
  intl: ^0.17.0
  datetime_picker_formfield: ^1.0.0
  json_annotation: ^3.0.1
  pdf: ^3.4.1
  advance_pdf_viewer:
    git: https://github.com/ncdm-stldr/pdf_viewer.git
  data_tables: ^1.0.3
  network_image_to_byte: ^0.0.1
  date_picker_timeline: ^1.2.0
  image: ^3.0.1
  line_icons: any
  printing: ^5.7.4
  flutter_datetime_picker: ^1.3.8
  flutter_cache_manager: ^3.0.0
  back_button_interceptor: ^4.2.4
  google_maps_flutter: ^2.0.4
  provider: ^4.1.3
  progress_dialog: ^1.2.0
  image_picker: any
  image_cropper: ^1.2.0
  flutter_picker: any
  flutter_localizations:
    sdk: flutter
  file_picker: ^4.3.0
  cross_file: ^0.3.2
  cron: ^0.4.0
  app_tracking_transparency: ^2.0.2+1
  line_awesome_flutter: ^1.0.1
  flutter_screenutil: ^1.0.2
  animated_theme_switcher: ^1.0.5
  _fe_analyzer_shared: ^34.0.0
  theme_provider: ^0.5.0
  timer_builder: ^2.0.0
  ionicons: any
  dropdown_button2: ^2.0.0
  url_launcher: ^6.1.10
  flutter_i18n: ^0.32.4

dev_dependencies:
  dart_code_metrics: ^4.8.1
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter

  font_awesome_flutter: ^8.0.1

flutter_icons:
  image_path: "assets/img/icona.png"
  android: true
  ios: true

flutter:

  uses-material-design: true

  assets:
    - assets/images/
    - assets/icons/
    - assets/images/avatar.png
    - assets/images/addicon.png
    - assets/images/logo.png


  fonts:
    - family: WorkSansSemiBold
      fonts:
        - asset: assets/fonts/Work_Sans/WorkSans-SemiBold.ttf
    - family: WorkSansBold
      fonts:
        - asset: assets/fonts/Work_Sans/WorkSans-Bold.ttf
    - family: WorkSansMedium
      fonts:
        - asset: assets/fonts/Work_Sans/WorkSans-Medium.ttf

build.gradle
ext {
    compileSdkVersion = 31
}
buildscript {

    ext.kotlin_version = '1.6.0'
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.4'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0'
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.30.0'

    }
    subprojects {
        afterEvaluate { project ->
            if (project.hasProperty("android")) {
                android {
                    compileSdkVersion 31
                }
            }
        }
    }

}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
}
subprojects {
    project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
}
configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy {
        force 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.6.0'
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}

Code:
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugAssets'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
   > Failed to transform activity-1.6.1.aar (androidx.activity:activity:1.6.1) to match attributes {artifactType=android-assets, org.gradle.category=library, org.gradle.dependency.bundling=external, org.gradle.libraryelements=aar, org.gradle.status=release, org.gradle.usage=java-runtime}.
      > Execution failed for JetifyTransform: /Users/riccardo/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/androidx.activity/activity/1.6.1/23139afb40f2e445f869f2a5f07eb056b1661a3c/activity-1.6.1.aar.
         > Failed to transform '/Users/riccardo/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/androidx.activity/activity/1.6.1/23139afb40f2e445f869f2a5f07eb056b1661a3c/activity-1.6.1.aar' using Jetifier. Reason: null. (Run with --stacktrace for more details.)
   > Failed to transform annotation-experimental-1.3.0.aar (androidx.annotation:annotation-experimental:1.3.0) to match attributes {artifactType=android-assets, org.gradle.category=library, org.gradle.dependency.bundling=external, org.gradle.libraryelements=aar, org.gradle.status=release, org.gradle.usage=java-runtime}.
      > Execution failed for JetifyTransform: /Users/riccardo/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/androidx.annotation/annotation-experimental/1.3.0/5087c6f545117dcd474e69e1a93cacec9d7334af/annotation-experimental-1.3.0.aar.
         > Failed to transform '/Users/riccardo/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/androidx.annotation/annotation-experimental/1.3.0/5087c6f545117dcd474e69e1a93cacec9d7334af/annotation-experimental-1.3.0.aar' using Jetifier. Reason: null. (Run with --stacktrace for more details.)

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 9s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1


try flutter clean then flutter pub get and then build it again

yes buy not works

Add your build.gradle, pubspec.yml files to get better understanding of your environment

you use quite old dart sdk and packages, even the Kotlin version is 1.6, can you try updating them. Update flutter sdk to latest using flutter upgrade and after that run flutter pub upgrade. Also update your android studio for latest kotlin version. But as I can see you are using dart 2.0 upgrading from dart 2.0 to 3.0 is a very big step. Please be cautious when doing it thoroughly check out the migration guide.

Some of your package need higher flutter version like url_launche.From 6.1.9 url_launcher need minimum flutter 3.3 to run. But you are using older version of flutter. So please update and migrate ro latest stable version for better support.
